# Calculating expected values: $\mathbb{E}\{ X \vert Y > y \}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assuming I know the conditional expected value of the form $\mathbb{E}\{ X \vert Y=y \}$, how do I calculate $\mathbb{E}\{ X \vert Y >y \}$?

Comment: @user133281: you forgot the density of Y...

Comment: @user133281 thanks for your comment. Meaning in discrete case: $E( X \vert Y > y ) = \sum_{i=y+1}^{\infty} E( X \vert Y=i)$ ? But is then $E( X \vert Y > y) \in \text{dom}(X)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$E(X|Y>y)=\dfrac{\sum_{k=y+1}^{+\infty} E(X|Y=k)\cdot Pr[Y=k]}{1-\sum_{k=-\infty}^y Pr[Y=k]}=\dfrac{\sum_{k=y+1}^{+\infty} E(X|Y=k)\cdot Pr[Y=k]}{\sum_{k=y+1}^{+\infty} Pr[Y=k]}$$

If $Y\ge 0$ then the first expression maybe more useful.

Notice that $Pr[Y>y]=\sum_{k=y+1}^{+\infty} Pr[Y=k]=1-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{y} Pr[Y=k]$ and
$$Pr[Y=k|Y>y]=\dfrac{Pr[Y=k]}{Pr[Y>y]}\text{ if } k>y \text{ and zero otherwise.}$$

Comment: thanks, this is an interesting formula, can you tell me where it comes from?

Comment: By Bayes' rule: $Pr[Y=k|Y>y]=\dfrac{Pr[Y=k]}{\sum_{k=y+1}^{+\infty} Pr[Y=k]}$

Comment: And $E(X|Y\in A)=\sum E(X|Y=k)\cdot Pr[Y=k|Y\in A)$ where in our case $A=(y,+\infty)$

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately I don't understand the last one. Isn't there the denominator missing? As far as I understand this, the left hand side what I'm actually looking for and the right hand side is the nominator of your solution above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No the left side is not the nominator of my solution. The $Pr[Y=k|Y\in A]$ in left side of the second comment is the right side of the first comment.

Comment: To get the conditional expectation $E(X|Y>k)$ since you know $E(X|Y=k)$ we need to use the density or probability of Y **conditional** on $Y>y$. So we weight each $E(X|Y=k)$ by the conditional prob. The reason we don't sum $Y$ less than $y$ is that the conditional prob. for these $Y$ is zero. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question.

Here's how.

$$E(X|Y>y) = \frac{E\bigl( X I(Y>y) \bigr)}{\Pr(Y>y)},
$$

where $I$ is the *indicator function*, i.e. $I(Y>y)$ equals one if $Y>y$ and zero otherwise.  The numerator is

$$\int_y^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty x dF(x|y) dF(y) = \int_y^\infty E(X|Y=y) dF(y),$$

which simplifies to

$$\int_y^\infty E(X|Y=y) f(y) dy,$$

if $Y$ is continuously distributed and

$$\sum_j I(y_j>y) P(Y=y_j) E(X|Y=y_j),$$

if $Y$ is discretely distributed with possible outcomes $y_1,y_2,\dots.$

Hope this helps.